# tkinter Menu "state" not updating dynamically

Tags: tkinter, menu, state

I have a dropdown menu with options that are `state="disabled"` unless a list has items in it. However, the menu is only checking for the list on creation, not every time the user opens the menu. How do I update the state dynamically?

```python
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("New Test")
window.geometry("300x300")

my_list = []

root_menu = Menu(window)
window.config(menu=root_menu)

def addList():
    global my_list
    my_list.append("one")
    print(my_list)

def isListEmpty(theList):
    if len(theList) > 0:
        return "active"
    else:
        return "disabled"

def showList():
    global my_list
    print(my_list)

first_menu = Menu(root_menu, tearoff=False)
root_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=first_menu)
first_menu.add_command(label="Add to List", command=addList)
first_menu.add_command(label="Show List", state=isListEmpty(my_list), command=showList)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code is working as expected. `isListEmpty(my_list)` will be called only once and state will be assigned. I would suggest to check if list is empty, everytime you modify the list, and then change the state by calling `first_menu.entryconfig(2, state=NORMAL)` and DISABLED as required.

Comment: Thanks, I edited this post to include the solution I had found... weird that it's missing. My solution was to include postcommand=, essentially what you suggested: calling the update every time the menu is clicked.